# How to preserve user state in the transition between devices?

Tags: web, state

Recently I came across this problem that users get distracted when they are working with their mobile phones for example when a user is shopping online, forget to continue their task, and there is no solution that something can preserve the state and later he/she can continue the task from his/her desktop.I wonder what is a good solution for storing the user state. Moreover, here I'm concerned about web applications, so when a user wants to resume his unfinished work, it can be from a desktop computer while the work started from a mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to set a cookie as soon as they land on your site. Depending on how much data you want to save you could start immediately, after a search or probably the most viable would be when they add an item to the cart present them with the option of a guest login asking only for a username, use real time ajax to check the availability of the name OR present them with a random 4 digit number that could smoothly popup alerting them they can use it to restore their session on another device
You could also ask for an email address but I think users will prefer an anonymous name unless they are planning to fully register.

If they accept the guest login save the cookie, username/code, page & items to the database for a period of 24-72 hours.